# "If" and "else" C# not outputting correctly

Tags: c#, xml

I have an application that compared an xml file to a text file, and if the contents of a specific line of the xml is the same as the text file, the program outputs a 1, but if they are different, it outputs a 0. Unfortunatley I can't get it to output 1. It always seems to output a 0.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;



namespace CompareIt
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("2.xml"))
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                    {
                        if (reader.Name.ToLower() == "data")
                        {
                            string xml = reader.ReadOuterXml();

                            var xmlString = (from data in XDocument.Parse(xml).Elements()
                                             select data.Elements().First().Value).FirstOrDefault();

                            xmlString = xmlString.Replace("\n", "").Trim();

                            var fileString = File.ReadAllText(@"8.txt");
                            if (xmlString == fileString)
                                Console.WriteLine("1");
                            else
                                Console.WriteLine("0");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The XML file (the program is supposed to only read the data section):

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <root>
     <Data>
      <Seperator>1</Seperator>
     </Data>
     <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
      <SignedInfo>
        <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
        <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
        <Reference URI="">
          <Transforms>
             <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
           </Transforms>
           <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
           <DigestValue>GHOSJRUqcHnZ3M090/5/KhvghyQ=</DigestValue>
         </Reference>
       </SignedInfo>
      <SignatureValue>oib+LAXqJshDFm3YM63qkSsJxxF+t0uahGax8tLrjSPJUjW045iYvB4LJCgMeF9oxatbWnVB9hGbvtVnl4iewJDL3kjnjvot5CLozMOaIGJgdys5MP8ncx771itANTm8wi8KgnqVjGjvTakEmcdwcSdRXuCP1WGOwuXm5StkY8Q=</SignatureValue>
    </Signature>
    </root>
```

and the text file simply contains a:

```
1
```

when I do  `Console.WriteLine(fileString);`
or

```
Console.WriteLine(xmlString);
```

they do output the same thing though, like they are supposed to, which confuses me even more.

Comment: Have you attached the debugger to see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested your code and it works fine, the only reason may be that your text file contains new line after 1. You may try remove the new line just before the if statement. Use

```
fileString = fileString.Replace(Environment.NewLine,"");
  if(....) //your if
```

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I didn't realize that.

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code and I see that it outputs 1 when

```
<Data>
  <Seperator>1</Seperator>
</Data>
```

and it outputs 0 when

```
<Data>
  <Seperator>0</Seperator>
</Data>
```

Perfectly legal and correct output.

Have you tried to remove the contents of the BIN folder of your project? Then rebuild your project and make sure that the text file and xml file properties are set to "Copy if Newer" or "Copy Always" provided that these files are part of your project.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your text file also contain line break symbols, thus making strings different.

Answer (score 0):

How about making sure that File.ReadAllText really returns just one character? Start by outputting it for debug purposes, or trimming it.